# OpenCV installation Problems with Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c++, opencv, visual-studio-2013

I have installed OpenCV 2.4.8 with Visual Studio 2013 using instruction found all over the Internet. I modified the property sheets and everything, but I am still facing a problem with the installation. When I try to run a test program, it gives me the following error:

```
Cannot open source file opencv2/core/core.hpp  

Cannot open source file opencv2/highgui/highgui_c.h
```

Why does this error occur? I have followed all installation steps faithfully.

Although, I should point out one more thing: There weren't any instructions for VS 2013, but only for VS 2012, so I just modified it where it was necessary, like replacing vc11 with vc12.

Comment: have you set your include paths to the directory where opencv was installed? are the files there?

Comment: point your "additional include directories" at your_opencv_path/build

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have openCV directory in your project's include directory. You should add openCV's include directory not include\opencv2.

Can you give me your project's include inputs?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is not opencv installation issue. Make sure the include opencv path is correct in your solution.

You need to add correct header include paths and library paths in the red marked area for your project. Also after including that try to open the header files(opencv header files) from the solution using right mouse click "Open Document "something.h" " to make sure your included path is correct.

[image]